# Updating UFW (uncomplicated Firewall) doesn't affect existing connections

Tags: firewall

Can anyone tell me whether or not new or updated rules made to ubuntu (v10.10) UFW should affect existing connections? I have noticed that these only take effect the next time I try to reconnect, which doesn't seem to me the way a firewall should behave!

What I'm trying to achieve here is to simulate a connection being lost/dropped in a socket based client.

Is there any way to update these rules immediately so as they affect existing connection?

Answer (score 4):

if the connection is already on when you update the firewall, your connection is Established and you probably have a rule to allow Established and Related connections. This rule is necessary to allow answers from IPs you connect to.

After updating the firewall, you have to drop the connection or restart network or interface to drop the connection and loose the Established status.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can lock the firewall and force all connections to drop. Firestarter is a better firewall interface.