# ssh connection stays active even after I delete the UFW rule

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm on debian buster (10), headless.

I setup ufw rules to allow ssh from certain IP's only,  that works,
I can ssh in ,  I stay logged in....
From a console, I delete the rule,  but from the ssh session I can still work,  however if I logoff, I cannot log back in,

Question is:  how do I prevent an active connection from working after I delete the rule for that IP?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating UFW (uncomplicated Firewall) doesn't affect existing connections](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36845/updating-ufw-uncomplicated-firewall-doesnt-affect-existing-connections)